# How to create let property in Child class of NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, inheritance

I am getting error:

> Stored property 'date' requires an initial value.

```
class DateInfo: NSManagedObject {
    let date: Date

    init(date: Date, entity: NSEntityDescription, insertInto: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil) {
        self.date = date
        super.init(entity: entity, insertInto: insertInto)
    }
}
```

How i can resolve this

Comment: Stored properties must have initial value or make it optional by using `?`. For example let date: Date? or let date: Date!

Comment: i dont want to make it optional

Comment: thanks for suggestion @AnupKanjariya

Comment: If you don't want to make it optional then declare like let date: Date!. Then after you have to init this date.

Comment: But usually its work without "!" or "?". What is special about NSManagedObject. Why its not working here

Comment: https://medium.com/@agoiabeladeyemi/inheritance-in-swift-9fad7a05a40d have a look